# JMeter configuration for IBM MQ 8

Tags: configuration, jmeter, ibm-mq

I am trying to use JMeter to test IBM MQ 8.0
Does anyone have an example (maybe a screenshot) of the various parameters I need? I found several examples, but very inconsistent...
More precisely, what should I fill in?

[image: Screenshot]

- QueueConnection Factory?
- JNDI name Request Queue: some example shows a queue name; some a JNDI name. Now what?
- JMS selector?
- Any JMS properties?
- Any JNDI properties?
- InitialContext Factory?

I assume I want to use "myserver" at port 50000, with user "myuser" and password "mypassword".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to configure a JNDI context in MQExplorer before, and basically set the names of JNDI objects created there:

[image]

The following works for me with JMeter 3.2:

[image]
[image]

And don't forget to add the MQ JAR to the test plan:

[image]