# Jmeter JMS point to point to connect IBM MQ error ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got com.ibm.mq.jms

Tags: jmeter, jms, performance-testing, ibm-mq, jndi

jmeter, jms point to point : error: **Response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory**

config:
1. jmeter3.3
2. All the jars available in websphere mq 8.0 -installed folder are pasted in apache-jmeter-3.3\lib folder

[image: MQ jars]

3. also added javax.jms-api-2.0.1 in apache-jmeter-3.3\lib folder
4. initial context factory setup in MQ Explorer

[image: JNDI config]

5. jmeter config -

[image: jms point to point config]

6. JDK 1.8
7. MQ explorer : Eclipse SDK v3.6.2

Followed all the steps as described in : [JMeter configuration for IBM MQ 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200688/jmeter-configuration-for-ibm-mq-8/46238776#46238776)

[JMeter 3.2 Point-to-Point configuration for IBM MQ 8 => Java Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340608/jmeter-3-2-point-to-point-configuration-for-ibm-mq-8-java-exception/46357907#46357907)

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you don't need that many jars, you should download the relevant `8.x.x.x-WS-MQ-Install-Java-All.jar` package from the [Fix Central](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&uid=swg24037500) and come up with libraries like:

   - com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
   - com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
   - fscontext.jar
   - jms.jar
   - JSON4J.jar
   - providerutil.jar
2. I also think you should use [`com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/jms/JmsFactoryFactory.html)

See [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for detailed JMeter configuration instructions for IBM MQ load testing